# Undertow XNIO I/O thread consistently eat CPU

Tags: java, performance, network-programming, undertow

I observed my application (based on undertow) constantly eat CPU percentage after running a while:

[image]

In the end I found if I suspend one of the XNIO I/O thread the CPU percentage will be released.

**The stack frame after suspended the I/O thread:**

[image]

**The CPU consumption after suspended and resumed that thread:**

[image]

Any idea what triggered this issue?

**Updates**

The suspended place of normal I/O thread:

[image]

The suspended place of error I/O thread:

[image]

**Update 2 - More findings**

There are dead loop found in the logic:

1. WorkerThread call `select`:
   [image]
2. Thread interupted:
   [image]
3. Selected key is `null` and it breaks out the loop:
   [image]
4. It repeats the infinit loop again:
   [image]
5. And back to the `select()` call:
   [image]

Comment: Similar issue found on Netty: https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/4460 and https://github.com/netty/netty/pull/2868

Comment: Hello, could you find a solution for this? It seems we have the same issue and we are totally stuck.

Comment: @GelinLuo Could you solve your problem?